# MySQL Update value includes quotes

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I am trying to query an update to a MEDIUM TEXT column in mysql and am running into an issue where the medium text I want to upload contains single and double qoutes. Is there an encoding scheme I should be using to avoid this issue in my my SQL Query?

Query:
`UPDATE blocks SET content = "${file}" WHERE key = "${name}"`

File: `'Date: <input type="date">';`

Comment: _"Is there an encoding scheme"_ - [Use **single-quoted strings** in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html), and escape single-quotes with backslashes. Double-quotes should not be used for strings in SQL as the ISO SQL standard reserves those for escaped-identifiers (older versions of MySQL seemingly disregard ISO SQL, but MySQL 8+ is more compliant, so avoid using double-quoted-strings).

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP and NodeJS? ...I doubt you're using both simultaneously.